# align screen of lightning accordion section and data inside it

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I wanna match the size of lightning-accordion-section and data under it, currently accordion section is going outside of data screen, I wanna make it aligned.
How to do it?

HTML

```html
<lightning-accordion-section name="associatedClaimInformation" label="Associated Claim Information">
```

CSS

```css
:host { --sds-c-accordion-summary-color-background: var(--lwc-colorBackground,rgb(160, 160, 160)); }
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4yoB.png]

Comment: HTML - <lightning-accordion-section name="associatedClaimInformation" label="Associated Claim Information">

Comment: Please edit the question adding both HTML and CSS relevant code (accordion, its container and its children). Just the line of the accordion is not enough.